# Popup keeps showing up on iPad because it won't accept cookies

Tags: html, cookies

I have made a popup that is meant to load when my website loads.
I have added a cookie to remember if the user has seen the popup after closing it, so that they are not presented with the popup again. It's working well, apart from on the iPad the popup loads on every single page of the site.

Does anyone know the best way around this?

My cookie code is:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
             var today = new Date();
             var expire = new Date();
             if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
             expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
             document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                             + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
        }   
        $("#member").click(function(){
            SetCookie("subscribed","1");    
            $( "#Subscribe" ).dialog("close");          
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got cookies set to enabled? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give HTML5 Storage a try! See: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
// store an item in the localstorage
localStorage.setItem('popup_shown', true);

// get an item from localstorage
var popupShown = localStorage.getItem('popup_shown');
```